# Function to format Decimal numbers to a certain number of decimal places

Tags: ios, swift

I have function:

```
func toString(number: Decimal, scale: Int) -> String {
    return number
}
```

I need a function that in the "number" parameter - will receive a Decimal number, round it to the number  of decimal places (scale parameter) and return the result in the String.
Does anyone know how to do it?

Comment: Look up "NumberFormatter" – there must be hundreds of examples...

Answer (score 0):

```
func toString(number: Double, scale: Int)-> String 
{

    var tempNum = number*pow(10.0,Double(scale))
    tempNum.round(.towardZero)

    return "\(tempNum*pow(10,(-1)*Double(scale)))"
}
```

Comment: I have error in line: Binary operator '*' cannot be applied to operands of type 'Decimal' and 'Double'

Comment: Please make sure you copied the first line of the function in which I wrote "toString(number : Double..."

Answer (score 0):

```
extension decimal
    {
        func roundTo(places:Int) -> String
        {
            let divisor = pow(10.0, Double(places))
            return "\((self * divisor).rounded() / divisor)"
        }
    }
```

I think this extension could help you. I use this is nearly every project.

Comment: I have error in line: number.roundTo(places: scale) - Value of type 'Decimal' has no member 'roundTo'

Comment: edited my answer should work for decimal if you use it now. it has been a Double extension not an decimal extension.

Answer (score 0):

```
let numberFormatter = NumberFormatter()
numberFormatter.minimumIntegerDigits = 1
numberFormatter.minimumFractionDigits = 0

func toString(number: NSNumber, scale: Int) -> String {
    numberFormatter.maximumFractionDigits = scale
    return numberFormatter.string(from: number) ?? ""
}
```

EXAMPLES:

```
toString(number: NSNumber(value: 1234.5678), scale: 1) // ANSWER = 1234.6
toString(number: NSNumber(value: 1234.5678), scale: 2) // ANSWER = 1234.57
toString(number: NSNumber(value: 1234.5678), scale: 3) // ANSWER = 1234.568
toString(number: NSNumber(value: 1234.5678), scale: 4) // ANSWER = 1234.5678
toString(number: NSNumber(value: 1234.5678), scale: 5) // ANSWER = 1234.5678
```

Comment: I'm try your code: public func  toString( number: Decimal, scale: Int)-> String
    {
        return toString2(number: NSNumber(value: number), scale: scale)
    }

    func toString2(number: NSNumber, scale: Int) -> String {
        let numberFormatter = NumberFormatter()
        numberFormatter.minimumIntegerDigits = 1
        numberFormatter.minimumFractionDigits = 0
        numberFormatter.maximumFractionDigits = scale
        return numberFormatter.string(from: number) ?? ""
    } - and I have error: Argument labels '(value:)' do not match any available overloads